# React API console.log()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

**I'm confused about my API using pokemon, I tried it like in the picture, I'm confused why when I console.log(dataPokomen) the array that appears there are 4 arrays, isn't one enough, this is normal?. did i position the line of code wrong? thankyou**

Comment: Don't post an image of your code. post a minimum reproducible sample ?

Comment: This is React question, isn't it? Then Vue tag is irrelevant.

Comment: Your react component is re rendering multiple times

Comment: React strict mode can be observed to double-render components in development (but not in an optimized production build).  Additionally, your component will re-render when state is updated.  Compound these two things and you get multiple renders.  (Basically, what you're observing isn't a problem.  It's expected behavior.)

Comment: it's probably linked to StrictMode in dev. Components are rendered twice.